# map $x+y \le 1, x,y >0$ to $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Is there a bijective continuous function which can map $x+y \leq 1, x,y >0$ to $R^2$?

I appreciate any idea and comment.

Comment: Your region stays simply connected when $(0.5,0.5)$ is removed, but $\mathbb R^2$ with any point removed is not simply connected.

Comment: Does that help? @stewbasic Homeomorphisms might require that, but continuous bijections are not always homeomorphism.

Comment: The relevance of @stewbasic comment is that if $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection and $X$ is compact, $Y$ Hausdorff then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in this case it would have to a homeomorphism by invariance of domain, I think? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Which is not actually relevant, because the domain of sucha  function would not be compact. @FaraadArmwood

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry you are right, good point.

Comment: Why stewbasic's idea is wrong? If $f$ is a continuous function from a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, and if $E$ is a connected subset of $X$, then $f(E)$ is connected. Can somebody please explain why we can't use this here?

Comment: Maybe @DEW meant $x + y < 1$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta the answer given by stewbasic is correct simply by invariance of domain which only requires injectivity.

Comment: My argument was incorrect. Invariance of domain requires an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$. I relied on the codomain (after removing a point) failing to be simply connected; it's still connected.

Comment: @JulienClancy I did mean less than or equal to 1

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible but it seems fairly difficult to prove.  Note that it _is_ possible if you add the point $(0,1)$ to your region.

Comment: @EricWofsey could you sketch how to construct the map with $(0,1)$?

Comment: @stewbasic: Imagine that instead of a triangle with a half-open edge, you had the open unit upper half-disk together with the segment $[0,1)\times\{0\}$.  Now use the map $z\mapsto z^2$ to get a continuous bijection to the open unit disk.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh sorry misread. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be quite similar in spirit to what stewbasic suggested in a comment, with the intermediate steps made more explicit.

Let's first look at what happens if we approach a point $a\in \overline{D}\setminus D$. Here, I write $D=\{(x,y): x,y>0, x+y\le 1\}$, and the closure is taken in $\mathbb R^2$.

I claim that if we had a homeomorphism $\varphi: D\to\mathbb R^2$, then $|\varphi(x_n)|\to\infty$ for any sequence $x_n\in D$ with $x_n\to a$ for such an $a$. This follows because otherwise $\varphi(x_n)\to y\in\mathbb R^2$ on a subsequence, but this contradicts the fact that also $y=\varphi(b)$ for some $b\in D$, and then a whole neighborhood of $y$ is obtained as the image of a neighborhood of $b$, so $\varphi$ would not be injective.

So we obtain an extended continuous surjective map $\varphi: \overline{D}\to S^2$, by mapping that part of the boundary that wasn't in $D$ to start with to $\infty$. Now the boundary of our triangle $\overline{D}$ gets mapped to a Jordan curve $C$ on $S^2$, and we can now take two points $a,b\in S^2$ (one from the interior and one from the exterior region of $C$) that can not be joined on $S^2$ without crossing $C$.

However, they can clearly be joined in this fashion on $D$, so we have obtained a contradiction.

**Remark:** This doesn't quite address the original question (which I hadn't read carefully enough), it shows that there is no homeomorphism. The continuity of $\varphi^{-1}$ is used in the third paragraph.

Comment: Though I haven't checked carefully, aspects of this argument make me uneasy. Particularly, the region $D$ together with _one_ of the acute corners _does_ admit a continuous bijection to the plane, so this argument, if correct, must fail to apply to the modified region.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: The part that fails is that the extension to $\overline{D}$ no longer maps continuously to $S^2$ because the added corner has a finite image while nearby points get mapped to $\infty$.

Comment: My apology for the unspecific comment. In the middle of checking the details, I was called away, and unsure when I'd be able to come back (or whether I'd remember to). My doubt was in the third paragraph (since OP isn't assuming $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, an issue addressed by your edit): If $D$ is the "modified" triangle (including a corner), it's not true that a continuous bijection to the plane maps the "omitted boundary" to infinity. That said, I agree you've handled the "homeomorphism" case. And again, my apology for the hasty note.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: The actual question seems quite a bit harder. I believe it should follow by showing that the plane minus the image of the "boundary segment" (which would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ if we had a continuous bijection) will not be simply connected, by just considering the various cases of what can happen when we approach the (ideal) endpoints. I haven't been able to make a proof out of this though.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the boundary $x+y \lt 1$ as you say in a comment, you can make such a bijection because the set is open. First take your favorite bijection $(0,1) \leftrightarrow \Bbb R$.  Mine is $z \leftrightarrow \tan (\pi (z-\frac 12))$.  Now given a point in your triangle, biject it to the open unit square by $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (\frac x{1-y}, \frac y{1-x})$, now apply the stretch to $\Bbb R$ independently in each axis.